# Count files in each folder

Tags: php

I tried to count files in each subfolder. For example

first subfolder : 4 files
second subfolder : 6 files 
...

Now my function count files in directory which I select in array:

```
if (!is_dir($subentry) && $gallery_dir[0]) {
```

How to can I count and list number of files in each subdirectory? But not sum elements from all subdirectories but in each subdirectory start counting from 0.

This is what I tried so far:

```
$folderCount = $fileCount = $galleryItemCount = 0;
$dir ='./product_img/';
//. means current directory
//if you wanna a learn a folders inside use opendir('path')
$gallery_dir = array();
$gallery_subdir = array();
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            if (is_dir($dir.$entry)) {
                echo "Folder => " . $entry . "<br>";

                    $gallery_dir[] = $entry;

                    if ($subdir = opendir($dir.$entry)) {
                         while (false !== ($subentry = readdir($subdir))) {
                            if ($subentry != "." && $subentry != "..") {
                                if (!is_dir($subentry) && $gallery_dir[0]) {
                                    echo "Folderrrr => " . $subentry . "<br>";  
                                    $gallery_subdir[] = $subentry;
                                    $galleryItemCount++;
                                    echo $gallery_dir;
                                }
                            }
                         }
                        closedir($subdir);
                    }
                 $folderCount++;
            } else {
                echo "File   => " . $entry . "<br>";
                $fileCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    //echo $galleryItemCount++;
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "File in aech folder" . $galleryItemCount. "<br />";
    echo "Total Folder Count : " . $folderCount . "<br>" ;
    echo "Total File Count : " . $fileCount;
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$dir = "/some/directory";
$counts = array (
    $dir => 0
);

$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator ($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator ($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($iterator as $pathname => $file)
{
    if ($file->isDir ())
    {
        $counts [$file->getPathname ()] = 0;
        continue;
    }
    $counts [$file->getPath ()] ++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it very kind with me

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Iterators. It's a bit tricky to get the file count per folder though.

First, wire up the Iterators. Pass the path you want to traverse:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
        '/path/you/want/to/traverse',
        RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS
    ),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
```

The option `SKIP_DOTS` will make the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` ignore `.` and `..`. The option `SELF_FIRST` is required for inclusion of directories. By default, only leaves, e.g. files, are considered.

With the Iterator wired up, you just need to do

```
foreach ($iterator as $fileObject) {
    if ($fileObject->isDir()) {
        $fileObject->setInfoClass(FilesystemIterator::class);
        $directoryIterator = $fileObject->getFileInfo();
        $directoryIterator->setFlags(FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
        $fileCount = iterator_count($directoryIterator);

        echo "$fileObject => $fileCount", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

This will print each folder name along with the file count in each of these folders. Like I said, it's a bit tricky to get the file count. This is because by default the `foreach` will return `SplFileObject` instances for the directories. Those are not countable. Thus we need to set the `FileSystemIterator`. That can be counted.

Note: if `FilesystemIterator::class` is not supported yet by your PHP Version, either update to a more recent version or pass in `'FileSystemIterator'` as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Example function:

```
    function dirs($dir)
    {
        if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
            while ($DF = readdir($handle)) {
                if ($DF != '.' && $DF != '..') {
                    $TYPE = is_dir($dir . "/" . $DF)?":DIRS":":FILES";
                    $List[$dir][$TYPE] = isset($List[$dir][$TYPE]) ? ++$List[$dir][$TYPE] : 1;
                    $List[$dir . "/" . $DF] = is_dir($dir . "/" . $DF) ? dirs($dir . "/" . $DF) : $DF;
                }
            }
        }
        return $List;
    }

    var_dump(dirs("framework"));
```

Will return an array list of files and folders, with a COUNT index for DIRS/FILES

```
            array (size=9)
      'framework' => 
        array (size=2)
          ':FILES' => int 6
          ':DIRS' => int 2
      'framework/.htaccess' => string '.htaccess' (length=9)
      'framework/composer.json' => string 'composer.json' (length=13)
      'framework/config.ini' => string 'config.ini' (length=10)
      'framework/index.php' => string 'index.php' (length=9)
      'framework/lib' => 
        array (size=24)
          'framework/lib' => 
            array (size=2)
              ':DIRS' => int 3
              ':FILES' => int 20
```